# Deleting legend entries with blank series name using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I'm trying to add in a subroutine that will delete the legend entries for series with blank names, in a line graph. Blank names arise when the series in question is disabled, this is done via another routine.

I've been using the code below but I end up losing the legend entries for series that don't have blank names, and I'm unsure of where I'm going wrong? For reference I have five series in total.

```
  Sub LegendRemover()
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim chtob As ChartObject
  On Error Resume Next

  Call Open_Results

      Set chtob = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 8")
      For i = chtob.Chart.SeriesCollection.Count To 1 Step -1
      If chtob.Chart.SeriesCollection(i).Name = "" Then
          chtob.Chart.Legend.LegendEntries(i).Delete
        End If
      Next i

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand where things goes wrong in your code? What happens if you remove your `On Error Resume Next` statement? I tried your code (slighly modified) and did not find any problems...

Comment: @Gowire The issue is that the code is deleting legend entries for series that do not have blank names (it's also deleting those that are actually blank), but the problem is I'm missing legend entries that should be there. I don't get an actual VBA error. Hope that clarifies things

Comment: You cannot get any error messages with `On Error Resume Next` activated. The code literally continues with the next line when an error occurs.

Comment: @Nacorid Apologies if I was not clear, but the issue isn't that I'm receiving an error message. The issue is that the subroutine is deleting legend entries for series that do not have blank names, when it should only be removing those with blank names from the legend.

Comment: I understand your Problem. I wanted to inform you that, due to your `On Error Resume Next` Statement, whenever the line `If chtob.Chart.SeriesCollection(i).Name = "" Then` throws an error the next line `chtob.Chart.Legend.LegendEntries(i).Delete` will be executed.

Comment: here's the issue, when the code runs the first time, it works. however, since you've deleted legend entries, the count of legend entries no longer matches the count of series collections. after the first run, if legend 2 was deleted, 3 now becomes 2, and it will be deleted on the next run, and so on. you could leave the legend in place and delete the legend's `LegendKey`, but this will also remove the series from the chart. what exactly are you trying to accomplish with _disabling a series_?

Comment: @Nacorid I see, I'll remove that line of code.

Comment: @WhiteHat The worksheet has a checkbox control that allows the user to select a subset of the series to display in the graph. When the user selects to show series A & B, then the names of series C and D are set to be blank. However the lines corresponding to series C and D still remain in the legend key - I'd like to remove series C and D from the legend key completely, without deleting the series. I don't understand why it's removing series that don't have blank names considering the if statement in the subroutine? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's the issue, when the code runs the first time, it works.

however, since you've deleted legend entries,
the count of legend entries no longer matches the count of series collections.

here's a visual, let's say the name for series 2 is blank,
before first run...

```
series blank legend
1      n     1
2      y     2
3      n     3
4      n     4
```

after the first run, since legend 2 was deleted, 3 now becomes 2.

```
series blank legend
1      n     1
2      y     2
3      n     3
4      n
```

on the next run, original legend 3, now 2, is deleted, and so on...

```
series blank legend
1      n     1
2      y     2
3      n
4      n
```

---

rather than deleting the legend,
you can use the `IsFiltered` property on the series.
when `IsFiltered` is true, both the line and legend will be hidden, but not removed.
and can be shown later, if the name is added back...

see following snippet...

```
Sub LegendRemover()
  Dim chtob As ChartObject
  Dim seriesLine As series

  Set chtob = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 8")
  For Each seriesLine In chtob.Chart.SeriesCollection
    seriesLine.IsFiltered = (seriesLine.Name = "")
  Next seriesLine
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you, this has done the trick! I'm trying to add a few extra lines to get the series name to show again when it isn't blank, I've tried the following but getting an object required error:`code`   If (seriesLine.Name <> "") Then
  seriesLine.IsFiltered = False
  End If `code`

Comment: the above should add the series back when it is not blank, here --> `seriesLine.IsFiltered = (seriesLine.Name = "")` -- because `(seriesLine.Name = "")` will equal `False` when not blank...